# Adding an if statement into PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, unix

Would like to ask how to add an if statement into the following code.

What it presently does is list all of the news articles from the database under a title of their respective months/years and groups the articles under this:
i.e.
May 2012 - News A, News B
June 2012 - News C
July 2012 - News D

We are having an issue with stories prior to 1970, due to the unix date system being used.
I don't wish to change the system that we presently use due to it "working", however, if a fix could be found for this (i've tried minus figures....it doesnt work), OR if an if statement could be added into this code below, that stops articles from being displayed/groups being created for articles pre-1970 then this would be good :)

```
<h3>Archive</h3>
<? $news=$session->getNews("","","",1);?>
<? while($article=mysql_fetch_array($news)){?>
<? 
$date = $article['thedate'];
$year = date('Y', $date);
$month = date('F', $date);
?>
<h4><?=$month." - ".$year;?></h4>
<nav class="small">
<? $innernews=$session->getNews("",$month,$year);?>
<? while($innerarticle=mysql_fetch_array($innernews)){?>
<a href="/news/<?=$innerarticle['ftitle']?>" <? if($title==$innerarticle['ftitle']){?> class="active"<? }?>><?=$innerarticle['title']?></a>
<? }?>
</nav>
<? }?>
<h4>Pre-1970</h4>
<nav class="small">
<a href="#">See More - Currently Unavailable</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Comment: @MathewFoscarini You should not use w3schools

Comment: w3school links are not very well recieved on SO, especially when it comes to PHP, there is mostly crap to be found there: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @MathewFoscarini How/where did you learn to write such code?

Comment: It was simply the first thing when you google "php if". Which was about as much effort that I wanted to give this question. So thanks for drawing me back and wasting more of my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "crude" as Matthew Harrington requested:

```
<h3>Archive</h3>
<? $news=$session->getNews("","","",1);?>
<? while($article=mysql_fetch_array($news)){?>
<? 
$date = $article['thedate'];
$year = date('Y', $date);
$month = date('F', $date);
if ($year<1970) continue;
?>
<h4><?=$month." - ".$year;?></h4>
<nav class="small">
<? $innernews=$session->getNews("",$month,$year);?>
<? while($innerarticle=mysql_fetch_array($innernews)){?>
<a href="/news/<?=$innerarticle['ftitle']?>" <? if($title==$innerarticle['ftitle']){?> class="active"<? }?>><?=$innerarticle['title']?></a>
<? }?>
</nav>
<? }?>
<h4>Pre-1970</h4>
<nav class="small">
<a href="#">See More - Currently Unavailable</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Smuuf!

I do have another questions - for some reason its showing duplicate months (only May's however?) do i need to put this into a new post?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Epoch Fail]

Okay, now for serious stuff.

Firstly, you seem to be dropping in and out of PHP needlessly. It's okay to mave more than one line of PHP! Second, you're using short-tags. While this may work, it may not. It's best to always use `<?php` (unless you're using PHP 5.4 or newer, in which case you can use `<?=$something?>` to echo something regardless of settings).

Now, on to the actual problem.What you could do is:

```
$year = ...;
if($year == 1970) echo "Sorry, news is not available for this date.";
else {
    // rest of your code to show news here
}
```

Comment: @DarylGill XKCD has a strip for everything, and yet he still comes out with fresh new stuff... He's amazing XD

Answer (score 0):

In your `<? while($innerarticle=mysql_fetch_array($innernews)){?>` Code, modify your query on `$innernews` Select Dates after you wish to stop showing by using the syntax `>`

it would also be better to provide how your `$innernews` And `$news` Variable is being set

Answer (score 0):

You could change it from `date()` to php's [object-oriented `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).
*note* - This requires php v. >= 5.2.0

```
<?
$date = $article['thedate'];
$dt = new DateTime($date);
$year = $dt->format("Y");
$month = $dt->format("F");
?>
```